# Valuating Custom Amortization Schedule Libor IRS with QuantLib

Tags: programming, swaps, quantlib

I got to bootstrap the OIS and Libor 3M swap curves, and now I'd like to valuate some simple Libor3M - Fix IRS with QuantLib (in python). My problem is that some of the instruments I have to valuate have custom amortization structure. Are there any examples on how to valuate a swap with a custom amortization schedule?

Answer (score 3):

To value a Swap with amortizations, you can feed a vector (list in python) with the notionals.

```
calendar = ql.TARGET()
start = ql.Date(17,6,2019)
maturity = calendar.advance(start, ql.Period('2y'))

fixedSchedule = ql.MakeSchedule(start, maturity, ql.Period('1Y'))
fixedLeg = ql.FixedRateLeg(fixedSchedule, ql.Actual360(), [100, 50], [0.01])

floatSchedule = ql.MakeSchedule(start, maturity, ql.Period('6M'))
floatLeg = ql.IborLeg([100, 100, 50, 50], floatSchedule, ql.Euribor6M(), ql.Actual360())

swap = ql.Swap(fixedLeg, floatLeg)
```

Comment: David, thanks for the example, its very clear. As I see, the dates schedule (fixed, starting, end and payment date) is created automatically. Is there a way to pass also a custom date schedule with the notional vector you mentioned?

Comment: Sure, ql.Schedule([ql.Date(15,6,2020), ql.Date(15,12,2020), ql.Date(15,6,2021)])